# How to use id of elements of activity using intent communication

Tags: android

In android suppose we intent an activity2 from activity1..so how can we use or get the ids of elements of activity2(such as relative layout etc) in activity1..and code in activity 1 using the element of activity 2

Comment: can u please clear/elaborate your question

Comment: That's not something you should be trying to do - each Activity's UI element are its alone.  At most, you should be sending some kind of request between them, but one in terms of abstract goals, not element id's.

Comment: I want to set the background of activity 2 using the onclick command of button present in activity1 that's why I need the id of layout of activity2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are trying to change the UI of `Activity1` based on `Activity 2` then you should start it as `child activity` and use `onActivityResult`.
2. If you are trying to access some values of `Activity1` in `Activity 2` then you can pass them via bundle.

Comment: can we pass the id of relative layout using bundle?

Comment: what are you gonna do by passing the ID. ?? i dn get the point.! :-/

Comment: I want to use the command rellayout.setbackground(R.drawable.img).

Comment: i hav some buttons(10-15) in activity1 and onclick of particular button activity2 should be displayed with particular background.

Comment: During the activity 2 start you need to send a value in bundle from activity1 and in activity2 'oncreate' method you should set the background of relative layout based on the bundle value